# Pointer does not lock in minecraft on linux, I tried using gamescope but I have an nvidia gpu which isn't supported. Any ideas?

Tags: linux, minecraft, nvidia

I use Arch linux with KDE plasma, 2 monitors, and an NVIDIA GTX 1660 ti graphics card.
I tried using GameScope but I later found out that it only supports AMD GPUs. I couldn't thinks of any other solutions.

when I move my mouse quickly it leaves into the other screen, this problem usually appears in windows as well, in that case what I usually do is use a program that turns minecraft into borderless fullscreen mode or something similar

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. For me, the pointer would only fail to stay locked to the window after alt-tabbing away from Minecraft and back again once. I haven't been able to solve the root issue, but I have worked around it. When I alt tab back into Minecraft, I hit escape (so the menu shows up), then un-fullscreen, then fullscreen it again (the default keybind for this is F11 I believe). After that, my pointer stays locked until I alt tab again. I've just made it a habit to hit escape and F11 twice after alt tabbing back into Minecraft. Hope this helps.